# Calculate Percentage in HTML Table - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am just trying to get the percentage in html table in second row 
**Database Consensus**.

So just tried that jQuery

```
var TableData = new Array();

jQuery('#myTable tr').each(function(row, tr){
    TableData[row]={
        "1st" : jQuery.trim(jQuery(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text())
        , "2nd" :jQuery.trim(jQuery(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text())
        , "3rd" : jQuery.trim(jQuery(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text())
        , "4th" : jQuery.trim(jQuery(tr).find('td:eq(5)').text())
    }
}); 
TableData.shift(); 
TableData.sort();

var First = [];
var Second = [];
var Third = [];
var Fourth = [];


for (var i = 0; i < TableData.length - 1; i++) {
    if (TableData[i + 1]['1st'] == TableData[i]['1st']) {
    First.push(TableData[i]['1st']);
    }
    if (TableData[i + 1]['2nd'] == TableData[i]['2nd']) {
    Second.push(TableData[i]['2nd']);
    }
    if (TableData[i + 1]['3rd'] == TableData[i]['3rd']) {
    Third.push(TableData[i]['3rd']);
    }
    if (TableData[i + 1]['4th'] == TableData[i]['4th']) {
    Fourth.push(TableData[i]['4th']);
    }
}

var first = First.length;
var total = TableData.length;
var percent = first/total * 100;
jQuery('.1st').text(First[0] + "\n" + "(" + percent + "%"+")");
var second = Second.length;
var percent = second/total * 100;
jQuery('.2nd').text(Second[0] + "\n" + "(" + percent + "%"+")");
var third = Third.length;
var percent = third/total * 100;
jQuery('.3rd').text(Third[0] + "\n" + "(" + percent + "%"+")");
var fourth = Fourth.length;
var percent = fourth/total * 100;
jQuery('.4th').text(Fourth[0] + "\n" + "(" + percent + "%"+")");
```

But i am not getting right percentage :(

I am not have very good experience in jQuery but tried Here is demo

http://jsfiddle.net/bcHsy/33/

Comment: What are these percentages of? I look at the code itself and it looks like static text.

Comment: No its not a static text please check the second row "Database     Consensus" its dynamic..

Comment: `<span style="color: #d89b5a;" class="4th">J.Bosa
(24%)</span>` That's all there is the Database Consensus goes to itself `_self` Yeah they are static, this is a mockup. The percentages would be from a database of which you pay a subscription for probably. Have you tried `var fourth = $('.4th').text();` ?

Comment: see this is what in fourth column actually `p align="center"><span style="color: #d89b5a;" class="4th">M.Jack (58%)</span></p>`

Comment: Please read the code in deep. All things is go with jquery and changing the row with script its not static

Comment: i just rewroet this for you for fun.. still not perfect but hope this helps.. http://jsfiddle.net/jyLpudbn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not much of a Fiddler, so I'm not sure that the link will even work, but I think that this might work:

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/sscotti/z0skkahy/)

I mostly changed the HTML in one section:

```
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ffffff"> 
        <p align="left">
            <a href="" target="blank"><span style="color: #d89b5a;"><strong>Database &nbsp; &nbsp; Consensus</strong></span></a>
        </p>
        </td>
        <td> 
        <p align="center">
            <span style="color: #d89b5a;">-------</span>
        </p>
        </td>
        <td> 
        <p align="center">
            <span style="color: #d89b5a;" class="1st">L.Tunsil</span>
        </p>
        </td>
        <td> 
        <p align="center">
            <span style="color: #d89b5a;" class="2nd">C.Wentz</span>
        </p>
        </td>
        <td> 
        <p align="center">
            <span style="color: #d89b5a;" class="3rd">J.Ramsey</span>
        </p>
        </td>
        <td> 
        <p align="center">
            <span style="color: #d89b5a;" class="4th">M.Jack</span>
        </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

and some of the JS:

```
var TableData = new Array();
var Picks = new Array();    
jQuery('#myTable tr').each(function(row, tr){
                if (row == 1) {
        Picks[0] = jQuery.trim(jQuery(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text());
        Picks[1] = jQuery.trim(jQuery(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text());
        Picks[2] = jQuery.trim(jQuery(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text());
        Picks[3] = jQuery.trim(jQuery(tr).find('td:eq(5)').text());
        }
    TableData[row]={
        "1st" : jQuery.trim(jQuery(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text())
        , "2nd" :jQuery.trim(jQuery(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text())
        , "3rd" : jQuery.trim(jQuery(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text())
        , "4th" : jQuery.trim(jQuery(tr).find('td:eq(5)').text())
    }
}); 

TableData.shift();
TableData.shift();
TableData.sort();

var First = [];
var Second = [];
var Third = [];
var Fourth = [];


for (var i = 0; i < TableData.length; i++) {
    if (TableData[i]['1st'] == Picks[0]) {
    First.push(TableData[i]['1st']);
    }
    if (TableData[i]['2nd'] == Picks[1]) {
    Second.push(TableData[i]['2nd']);
    }
    if (TableData[i]['3rd'] == Picks[2]) {
    Third.push(TableData[i]['3rd']);
    }
    if (TableData[i]['4th'] == Picks[3]) {
    Fourth.push(TableData[i]['4th']);
    }
}

var first = First.length;
var total = TableData.length;
var percent = first/total * 100;
jQuery('.1st').text(First[0] + "\n" + "(" + percent + "%"+")");
var second = Second.length;
var percent = second/total * 100;
jQuery('.2nd').text(Second[0] + "\n" + "(" + percent + "%"+")");
var third = Third.length;
var percent = third/total * 100;
jQuery('.3rd').text(Third[0] + "\n" + "(" + percent + "%"+")");
var fourth = Fourth.length;
var percent = fourth/total * 100;
jQuery('.4th').text(Fourth[0] + "\n" + "(" + percent + "%"+")");
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, at least the percentages are correct ?

Comment: Please let me know which html section you have changed ?

Comment: Sorry the problem is still there you just used the name of players statically. Names are also dynamic for example L.Tunsil its should count names in table and get the which used mostly Let me know if you understand ?

Comment: By the way i can go with this script :) Thank you so much your help.